# How do I distinguish RadioButtons?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a for-loop with a `RadioButton` at each iteration. My problem is I don't know how to distinguish every single `RadioButton` once I validate my form (how to retrieve their value?) . I have a model for printers :

```
public class Printer{
     public int id{ get; get;}
     public string printerName { get; set; }
}
```

Which itself is part of another model :

```
public class FinalSiteModel 
{
    public string name{ get; set; }
    public List<Printer> printers{ get; set; }
    public bool selected { get; set; }
}
```

Then as I pass it to the view :

```
for(var i = 0; i < Model.printers.Count() ; i++)
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.selected, new {  Name = "groupRadio"});
    @Html.Label(Model.printers[i].printerName);
}
```

I think something is wrong with the way I wrote my RadioButton. I initially used the boolean `selected` inside of the `PrinterModel` but my problem then came from the fact that the radiobuttons didn't group since I used

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.printers[i].selected, new {  Name = "groupRadio"});
```

and this bit : `m => m.printers[i].selected` created a different name for each radiobutton, hence when I check several radiobuttons at the same time, which I don't want.

I'm guessing I should add a parameter to `RadioButtonFor` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your radio buttons need a value to bind to your `selected` property. However that property needs to be `int`, not `bool`

```
public class FinalSiteModel 
{
    ...
    public List<Printer> Printers { get; set; }
    public int SelectedPrinter { get; set; }
}
```

and then in the view

```
foreach(var printer in Model.Printers)
{
    <label>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedPrinter, printer.Id, new { id = "" })
        <span>@printer.Name</span>
    </label>
}
```

Note the 2nd parameter of `RadioButtonFor()` adds the `value` attribute based on the `Id` property of `Printer`, and the `new { id = "" }` removes the `id` attribute which would otherwise be invalid because the method generates duplicates

The value of `SelectedPrinter` will now contain the `Id` of the selected `Printer` when you POST your form.

As a side note, never attempt to change the `name` attribute using `new {  Name = "groupRadio" }` - it would not bind to your model.

Comment: Good thing you're always around Stephen, thanks once again :)